# C# Entity Framework XUnit Tests Always Failing

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, xunit

I'm currently trying to setup some tests to check that my code is working. I've managed to set it up with the .NET 6 minimal API and use a test db context instead, however, when I have multiple tests all the tests are failing.

I believe the reason for this is because they are running parallel which is obviously causing a conflict with the database context.

To counteract this, I've tried an in memory database and create a new database based on a guid which is resolved before the test, however, I've read that in memory databases aren't the best for testing as it's not a true reflection. So I've opted to use a test SQL Server. Which I plan on tearing down after each test - I know this may take a lot longer than usual but I'm happy to take that given it's an accurate reflection of the code interacting with the database.

However, for that I think I need to run the tests individually rather than in parallel.

My test is really simple, it just tests a 200 and a count. Running them individually works perfectly.

```
public class GetUserEndpointTest()
{
  [Fact]
  public async Task OnSuccess_ReturnStatusCodeOk()
  {
    await using var application = new Application();
    var client = application.CreateClient();

    var response = await client.GetAsync("/v1/users");
    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
  }

  [Fact]
  public async Task OnSuccess_ReturnsTheCorrectUserCount()
  {
    await using var application = new Application();
    var client = application.CreateClient();

    var users = await client.GetFromJsonAsync<List<User>>("/v1/users");
    users.Count.Shound().Be(1);
  }  
}
```

My application factory is just simple:

```
class Application : WebApplicationFactory<Program>
{
  protected override IHost CreateHost(IHostBuilder builder)
  {
    builder.ConfigureServices(services =>
    {
      services.RemoveAll(typeof(DbContextOptions<ApplicationContext>));
      services.AddDbContext<ApplicationContext>(options =>
        {
          options.UseSqlServer(
            "Server=localhost;Database=testing_database;Trusted_Connection=True;"
          );
        });
     });

     return base.CreateHost(builder);
  }
}
```

Comment: And... What is your question?

Comment: I suppose there’s multiple. How do I get the tests so they don’t run in parallel? Is using a database the best approach here?

Comment: In our company we are starting docker container with DB and running tests on it. To run tests sequentially there is a config in VS, or `-m:1` parameter when running `dotnet test` in CI.

Comment: Chech this for fast db reset between tests https://github.com/jbogard/Respawn

Comment: Also check this for tests settings https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/configure-unit-tests-by-using-a-dot-runsettings-file?view=vs-2022

Comment: @Artur I really like that idea of the docker container, I'll have to explore that. I don't suppose you have any reference links that could be of use? Looking into Respawn now, although I don't truly understand how it works the idea of it looks amazing.

Comment: We are using lib that I developed, maybe I'll ask to make it open source. But you can check this project for now https://github.com/HofmeisterAn/dotnet-testcontainers

Comment: Wouldn't mocking the database be a better option to it?

Comment: @virouz98 it depends on what level of testing you want to achieve. Mocking DB is definitely a bad idea. You either should mock your dal and write separate integration tests for dal only against real DB (that's what we tend to do) or make a complete integration test with real DB. Anyway, don't try to mock EF, such tests are useless and hard to maintain. When using EF, you want to make sure you are doing it the right way, and this can be achieved only with integration tests against real DB (not InMemory and not SQLite).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When testing with XUnit, you can prevent parallel execution of the tests by putting them in a "collection". You declare which tests belong to the collection by "decorating" the class declaration with a `Collection` attribute.

This is explained at https://xunit.net/docs/running-tests-in-parallel

For example:

```
    [Collection("NonParallelTestCollection")]
    public class MyUnitTests1
    {
    // your tests here ...
    }

    [Collection("NonParallelTestCollection")]
    public class MyUnitTests2
    {
    // your tests here ...
    }
```

In this example, none of the tests in either of the classes will run in parallel.