# xunit throw AggregateException(User does not have permission to alter database) while each test is run individually

Tags: c#, testing, integration-testing, xunit

I try to make some integration testing for repository pattern with the database, I face a problem that each test run individually fine but when it tries to run all tests xUnit throw the following error

> Message: 
> System.AggregateException : One or more errors occurred. (User does not have permission to alter database 'PharoesTechDBTest', the database does not exist, or the database is not in a state that allows access checks.
> ALTER DATABASE statement failed.) (The following constructor parameters did not have matching fixture data: DatabaseFixture fixture)
> ---- Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException : User does not have permission to alter database 'PharoesTechDBTest', the database does not exist, or the database is not in a state that allows access checks.
> ALTER DATABASE statement failed.
> ---- The following constructor parameters did not have matching fixture data: DatabaseFixture fixture

DatabaseFixture

```cs
public class DatabaseFixture : IDisposable
{
    public DatabaseFixture()
    {
        var factory = new ApplicationContextFactory();
        Context = factory.CreateDbContext(Array.Empty<string>());

        // drop and recreate new database
        Context.Database.EnsureDeleted();
        Context.Database.EnsureCreated();
    }
    public void Dispose()
    {
          Context.Dispose();
    }

    public ApplicationDbContext Context { get; }
}
```

**first Test class**

```cs
public class CategorysRepoTests : IClassFixture<DatabaseFixture>, IClassFixture<LoggerFixture>
{
    private readonly ICategoryRepo _repo;
    private readonly DatabaseFixture _dbfixture;

    public CategorysRepoTests(DatabaseFixture fixture, LoggerFixture loggerFixture)
    {
        _dbfixture = fixture;
        _repo = new CategoriesRepo(fixture.Context, loggerFixture.Logger);
    }

    [Fact]
    [Trait("Category", "IntegrationTest")]
    public async Task CreateCategorySuccessfully()
    {
        Assert.Empty(_dbfixture.Context.Categories);
        var newCategory = DataGenerator.CreateCategory();

        // insert category
        await _repo.AddAsycn(newCategory);
        _dbfixture.Context.ChangeTracker.Clear();

        // Check if ID was set
        Assert.True(newCategory.Id > 0);

        // Make sure that Category is in DB
        var categories = await _dbfixture.Context.Categories.Where(u => u.Id == newCategory.Id).ToListAsync();
        Assert.NotEmpty(categories);

    }
}
```

second test class

```cs
public class MediaTypeRepoTests : IClassFixture<DatabaseFixture>,IClassFixture<LoggerFixture>
{
    private readonly DatabaseFixture _dbfixture;
    private readonly IMediaTypeRepo _repo;

    public MediaTypeRepoTests(DatabaseFixture fixture,LoggerFixture logger)
    {
        _dbfixture = fixture;
        _repo = new MediaTypesRepo(_dbfixture.Context, logger.Logger);
    }

    [Fact]
    [Trait("Category", "IntegrationTest")]
    public async Task MediaTypeRepoContainsDatatOnNewlyCreatedDb()
    {
        
        var medias = await _repo.GetAllAsync();

        Assert.NotEmpty(medias);

    }
}
```

**DataGenerator**

```cs
public class DataGenerator
{
    public static Category CreateCategory()
    {
        return new Category
        {
            Title = "test title",
            ThumbnailImagePath = "some thubnail",
        };
    }
}
```

Why each one of them run individually but when I try to run together it throws error ??! Where is the flaw?

Comment: Sounds like the parallel execution of the tests might be causing them to interfere with each other. Try making a "Collection" of the tests to prevent their parallel execution. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71577600/c-sharp-entity-framework-xunit-tests-always-failing/71586419#71586419

Comment: @ChristopherHamkins yeas it was a parallelism issue, I voted on your answer many thanks for mentioning it

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by [@Christopher](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71577600/c-sharp-entity-framework-xunit-tests-always-failing/71586419#71586419) it was a parallelism issue, I solve it by disable the parallelism on the whole project level

```cs
global using Xunit;
[assembly: CollectionBehavior(DisableTestParallelization = true)]
```

read more about [Tests in Parallel](https://xunit.net/docs/running-tests-in-parallel)